# How to execute a command on behalf of a user if login is denied

Tags: linux, shell, tomcat, authentication

I need to run tomcat on behalf of `tomcat` user. But in `/etc/passwd` I have the following line:

```
tomcat:x:505:506::/usr/share/tomcat:/bin/nologin
```

So when I try to do this: `sudo su tomcat ./bin/startup.sh`

It complains about: `su: /bin/nologin: No such file or directory`

How do I execute the command with proper permissions?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I'm trying to reverse engineer the configuration and it's production. So I have to be delicate...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try running:

```
sudo -u tomcat ./bin/startup.sh
```

By avoiding `su` you avoid trying to invoke the user's login shell.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify shell with `-s` option

```
sudo su -s /bin/bash -c ./bin/startup.sh tomcat
```

Answer (score 1):

actually, the best way to do this is via **runuser**

the man page is here http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/runuser.1.html

this tool is used to deal with the situation as the developer said in his bolg

#### Whenever an service is running as root and wants to change UID using the shell it should use runuser.

http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/55588.html